# Why does my page's request require authentication?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

My problem is concerned with:
a blog homepage called via the `ArticlesController@index` function
the individual blog post pages called via `ArticlesController@show` function, and
the comment form to be embedded into the individual blog post pages that would post to `blog/{blog}/comment` and would invoke the `CommentsController@store` method

I have the following routes of concern defined in my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::resource     ('blog',                    'ArticlesController');

Route::resource     ('blog/{blog}/comment',     'CommentsController');
```

The `ArticlesController` is set to call the `auth` middleware for all functions except `index()` and `show($id)`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'index', 'show']);
}
```

When I attempt to access the individual blog post pages without the comment form, it works as expected and allows me to access the homepage and individual post pages without authentication.

Whereas when I have the comment form embedded into the individual post pages, it allows me to access the homepage but demands me to authenticate before I could access the individual post pages.

Can anyone tell me why it behaves so even though my `CommentsController` is a separate entity and it is not invoking the `auth` middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `except` argument should be an array

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
}
```

**Updated per comment**

If you look at the [code](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.html#method_middleware%20the%20middleware%20method%20is%20looking) for the middleware method if is looking for an array.

```
/**
 * Register middleware on the controller.
 *
 * @param  string  $middleware
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return void
 */
public function middleware($middleware, array $options = [])
{
    $this->middleware[$middleware] = $options;
}
```

As to why it worked before, who knows. I imagine that at some point along the chain of methods Laravel is converting a string to an array and that is why it worked.

You might want to consider writing a [test](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing) for your controller. That way you are not dependent on any particular moment of how it is working. You know it works the way you intended and that nothing you do changes the expected result.

Comment: Okay well, that solved my problem but why on Earth was it working fine (i.e. it was authenticating except for both `index` and `show` functions) before? Also, I get the fact that that's how the documentation says it should be but how does converting the `except` arguments into an array fix the issue.

Comment: @ikartik90 Updated my answer per your comment.